# Microsoft SQL Server 2005 XP_DELETE_FILE

Tags: sql-server

I've had the misfortune of inheriting a system, which is causing me great problems. It is running on SQL Server 2005 and the problem I have is within the database maintenance plan. A cleanup routine is using the undocumented XP_DELETE_FILE command and gets stuck on more or less a nightly basis.

It would appear that our nightly backup program (of which I have no control) is backing up a file which the XP_DELETE_FILE command is trying to delete. As opposed to either failing, or simply bypassing the file, it would appear to hang. This means no further steps within the maintenance plan are executed.

I've been looking for a solution for this along the lines of:

1. Not using the XP_DELETE_FILE command, or
2. Checking file access permissions before I run XP_DELETE_FILE.

But I've had no such luck. Anyone have any ideas or solutions, I would gladly appreciate them.

Regards

Code Sample:

```
      -- Delete old backup files
  IF (@CurrentCommandOutput02 = 0 AND @Verify = 'N' AND @CurrentCleanupDate IS NOT NULL)
  OR (@CurrentCommandOutput02 = 0 AND @Verify = 'Y' AND @CurrentCommandOutput03 = 0 AND @CurrentCleanupDate IS NOT NULL)
  BEGIN
    IF @BackupSoftware IS NULL
    BEGIN
      SET @CurrentCommand04 = 'DECLARE @ReturnCode int EXECUTE @ReturnCode = master.dbo.xp_delete_file 0, N''' + REPLACE(@CurrentDirectory,'''','''''') + ''', ''' + @CurrentFileExtension + ''', ''' + CONVERT(nvarchar(19),@CurrentCleanupDate,126) + ''' IF @ReturnCode <> 0 RAISERROR(''Error deleting files.'', 16, 1)'
    END

    IF @BackupSoftware = 'LITESPEED'
    BEGIN
      SET @CurrentCommand04 = 'DECLARE @ReturnCode int EXECUTE @ReturnCode = master.dbo.xp_slssqlmaint N''-MAINTDEL -DELFOLDER "' + REPLACE(@CurrentDirectory,'''','''''') + '" -DELEXTENSION "' + @CurrentFileExtension + '" -DELUNIT "' + CAST(DATEDIFF(mi,@CurrentCleanupDate,GETDATE()) + 1 AS nvarchar) + '" -DELUNITTYPE "minutes" -DELUSEAGE'' IF @ReturnCode <> 0 RAISERROR(''Error deleting LiteSpeed backup files.'', 16, 1)'
    END

    EXECUTE @CurrentCommandOutput04 = [dbo].[CommandExecute] @CurrentCommand04, '', 1, @Execute
    SET @Error = @@ERROR
    IF @Error <> 0 SET @CurrentCommandOutput04 = @Error
  END
```

Answer (score 0):

What kind of files are you trying to delete?

xp_delete_file is a SP from SQL 2000. It checks the first line of the file to be deleted to verify that it is either a SQL backup file or a SQL report file. It doesn't check based on the file extension.

maybe if you post some of your delete code it would be easier to help

Comment: It is trying to delete a SQL generated .BAK file.

Comment: ok, can you post the result of the line that calls the xp_delete_file procedure. It seems like you are missing one parameter in the end

Comment: That's one of the problems, it either completes the command and therefore there isn't any error, or it simply sits on that command for as long as I permit it. I killed it over the weekend after sitting on that command for 38 hours! It does work, about once every 4 days or so. I need it to work every night, or at least more often than not!

Comment: ok, but why does that impede you from posting the execution line? you can execute the code now, cant you? just add a print on the variable @CurrentCommand04.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a CLR function for doing the file operations. Create an assembly that manipulates the file (eg. using [`File.Delete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete.aspx), load this assembly in the system and mark with with `EXTERNAL_ACCESS` and use the CLR functions you added instead of the deprecated, undocumented XPs. See [How to: Create and Run a CLR SQL Server Stored Procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/5czye81z%28v=vs.80%29).